# Nativescript RadSideDrawer. I don't need back button

Tags: nativescript, drawer

I'm trying to make a simple app with Playground (https://play.nativescript.org/). I'm using "RadSideDrawer" as a side menu. I'm satisfied. BUT ... every time I use "RadSideDrawer" and I move from one page to another, inside the "ActionBar" a button appears whose function is to bring back to the left page (please have a look at this page https://www.attivitacollaterali.it/appdata/services/apps/RadSideDrawer.html). I don't need and want this button. How can I make it not appear? Thank you.
Or, if not, at least update "RadSideDrawer". I mean that if the button goes back, for example to the "Search" page from the "Home" page, it should highlight/select "Search" in the "RadSideDrawer" menu and not leave "Home". Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for the "clearHistory" option while navigating. When navigating to another page, you must do this:

```
this.router.navigate([url], { clearHistory: true });
```

Just make sure you're injecting RouterExtensions in your constructor:

```
constructor(private router: RouterExtensions) {}
```

That should clear the navigation stack when navigating, thus removing the button to go back to the previous page.

EDIT: If you want to retain the navigation stack, I believe you can also edit your action bar like this:

```
<ActionBar>
    <NavigationButton visibility="collapsed"/>
</ActionBar>
```

Comment: Now it works the way I wanted it to.
Just add "clearHistory: true" to the code snippet that allows you to navigate from one page to another, which in my case becomes:
 Frame.topmost().navigate({
        moduleName: componentRoute,
        transition: { name: "fade" },
        clearHistory: true
    });
Thanks again! I'm sorry, but I still can't figure out where to say this is solved.

Comment: To the left side of the answer there should be a checkbox underneath the up and down vote arrows. Clicking the checkbox marks the answer as solved. Glad I could help!